# Pass a parameter to a stored procedure in AS400 to match IN keywork

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures, ibm-midrange

I am trying to pass as parameter to a stored procedure as string that will match the `IN` syntax.

I defined the parameter as `CHARACTER` and if I am writing the following it works:

```
MPROMY IN ( '2','3' )
```

`MPROMY` is the column in the database table.

I am trying to replace the values with the parameter:

```
MPROMY IN ( PRIORDAYS )
```

`PRIORDAYS` is the parameter passed in.

Here is my code in C#:

```
var daysIn = "'2','3'";
return CallStoredProcedure(string.Format("CALL SPORDCMP('{0}')", daysIn));
```

I am getting the following error:

> ERROR [42000] [IBM][System i Access ODBC Driver][DB2 for i5/OS]SQL0104 - Token 1 was not valid. Valid tokens: ) ,.

What is the correct syntax to pass a parameter in order to work with IN keyword?

Comment: Have you confirmed that your stored procedure accepts dynamic sql? because otherwise your in will not work; also you should replace CALL SPORDCMP('{0}') with CALL SPORDCMP({0}) since you are already using quotes on your "in" variable

Comment: You want your IN() clause to check two possibilities, but you're only passing in a single value. The single value consists of the entire string `"'2','3'"` which is eight characters long. If you want two values, you need to pass two parameters. Alternatively, as @jclozano says, you need to construct a 'dynamic SQL' statement.

Comment: Can you please point me to an example, I am not clear how to do it at all.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I've done it. In my case I am passing a store number (will not be hard coded when in production).

I build the command. Tell it the parms. Execute the stored procedure.

```
                using IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries;
                //Create a command object
                cmd.Transaction = trans;
                cmd.CommandText = "libraryname.storedprocedurename";
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
```

ItemStoreNumber and ItemDesc are described in the model.

```
                // Build the Stored Procedure Paramaters - Build Input Value              
                iDB2VarChar stNumber = "0001"; //Get from store later
                iDB2Parameter parm = cmd.Parameters.Add("@ItemStoreNumber",     
                iDB2DbType.iDB2VarChar); 

                cmd.Parameters["@ItemStoreNumber"].Direction = 
                parameterDirection.Input;  

                cmd.Parameters["@ItemStoreNumber"].Value = stNumber;



                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                iDB2DataAdapter da = new iDB2DataAdapter();
                da.SelectCommand = cmd;
                da.Fill(dt);



                foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                {

                    StoreItem storeitem = new StoreItem();
                    storeitem.ItemStoreNumber = (String)
                    row["RSTORE"].ToString();    
                    storeitem.ItemDesc = (String) row["IDESC"].ToString();
                    storeitem.ItemUpc = (String)row["RUPC"].ToString();
                    storeitem.ItemUom = (String)row["ISUNIT"].ToString();
                    storeitem.ItemRpack = (String)row["RCPACK"].ToString();
                    storeitem.ItemRetailPrice = 
                    Convert.ToDecimal(row["RCRETAILP"].ToString());
                    myStoreItems.Add(storeitem);

                }

                return myStoreItems;
```

Comment: please explain how does it answer the question?

Comment: What I was trying to highlight was the definition of the IN parameter in my code. I had trouble passing parms to my stored procedure until I defined them.  iDB2Parameter parm = cmd.Parameters.Add("@ItemStoreNumber",     
                iDB2DbType.iDB2VarChar);                                                                                          cmd.Parameters["@ItemStoreNumber"].Direction = 
                parameterDirection.Input;